# Default position of a switch

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which version is correct?

1. Move all switches into their default positions.
2. Put all switches into their default positions.
3. Switch all switches into their default positions.
4. Bring all switches into their default positions.

Comment: None are incorrect, exactly. Other options: set, turn, flick, toggle, reset. But I'm curious what kind of switches have default positions. Are we talking up/down switches or things like dials? If they're dials then replace the word "switches" with "controls," e.g. "Reset all controls to their default positions."

Comment: @William, thanks for your answer. They are channel switches on a remote control, and some manufacturers assign default positions. The problem with this particular remote is that for safety reasons you cannot start it up, unless all switches are in their default positions.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks! Hey, you've piqued my curiosity. You don't have to answer this--I'm just being nosy--but you're not talking about a TV remote, are you? My TV remote has buttons, not switches, and no configuration of those buttons ever results in safety issues. This has got to be a remote for something like a model airplane, right?

Comment: The "default" way to say within the "default" technology circles is "**set** all switches to their default positions".

Comment: Hello @William. The remote is for a quadcopter.

Comment: @jhuk: Aha! You may not be talking primarily about *switches*, then. You're talking about sticks and levers and trimmers. You might have a mode switch, but it's possible the only true switch on your remote is the On/Off switch. With that in mind, this might be a good sentence to say what you want: "Place all controls into their default positions." Anyway, be safe & have fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the four possible answers you have give us, I would select

1. Move all switches into their default positions.

I might suggest an additional possible answer that I like better than what you have displayed here ... "into" is fine but "to" sounds better to me.

Set all switches into (to) their default positions.

Comment: I might say, "Ensure all switches are in their default positions." since I may not have to actually move some of them.